# Availability Zone for Elastic Block Storage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

If the Availability Zone for an Elastic Block Storage (EBS) volume is `us-east-1c`, can I mount it on an instance in `us-east-1a`? If not, what is the best way to migrate the volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EBS** volumes can only be mounted on an instance in the **same** availability zone.

One way you get a volume's data from one zone into another is through a snapshot. You snapshot one volume and then immediately create a new volume in a different zone from the snapshot.

See also:

[Creating an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)
[Restoring an Amazon EBS Volume from a Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html)

Comment: I assume the procedure is the same for an AMI backed by an EBS volume?

Comment: Yes, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html

Comment: I believe that AMIs, even those backed by EBS volumes can be launched from any availability zone. I think this is because the AMI is backed by a snapshot which does not have an AZ.